# print down the line and automatically updated continuouslyin

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

i have a command

```
import time
i=0
b=0
while(True):
   i=i+1
   b=b+1
   time.sleep(2)
   print('Jack: {} '.format(str(i)) ,end='')
   
   print('Han: {} '.format(str(b)) ,end='\r')
```

i want print this like

```
Jack: 1
Han : 1
```

in the next loop it still prints at that position only the number changes like this

```
Jack: 2
Han : 2
```

Note: Do not combine 2 prints into 1 print
I need ideal

Comment: Why not just a single `print(f'Jack: {i}\nHan:  {b}')`?

Comment: Incidentally I have no idea what your question title means....

Answer (score -1):

If I read what you want correctly, you want to update the number, not print a new line.  In which case use [blessings](https://github.com/erikrose/blessings) and print at the *location* on the screen instead.

Something like:

```py
from blessings import Terminal
from time import sleep

term = Terminal()
i = 0
while True:
    print(term.move(1, 1), f"I am a number: {i}")
    i += 1
    sleep(1)
```

Note that there are other terminal control libraries, I just like blessings.